# Lightning data table not showing header for button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image]

I amm specifying label and title attribute sttill not able to see header in the columns.

```
<lightning:datatable
                                            aura:id="attachmentDataTable"
                                            columns="{!v.columns}"
                                            class="PC-dataTable-table-wrapper"
                                            data="{!v.data}"
                                            keyField="Id"
                                            onsave ="{!c.onSave}"
                                            hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                            onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}" />
component.set('v.columns', [
           {
               type: "button", 
               initialWidth:100,
               typeAttributes: {
                   label:'View',
                   name:'View',
                   title:'View',
                   disabled: false,
                   value:'View',
                   
               }},
           {
               type: "button", 
               initialWidth:100,
               typeAttributes: {
                   label:'Delete',
                   name: 'DeleteRecord',
                   title:'Action',
                   disabled:false,
                   value: 'Delete',
                   
               }},
           {label:'Name', fieldName:'Name', editable:'true', type: 'text'},
           {label:'Private', fieldName:'IsPrivate', editable:'true', type: 'boolean'},
           {label:'Description',fieldName:'Description', editable:'true', type: 'textarea'},
           {label:'LastModifiedDate', fieldName:'LastModifiedDate',type: 'date'},
       ]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice on your columns which have a header, you specify a `label` attribute. But in your columns which do not, you only specify `type`, `initialWidth`, and `typeAttributes`. You should also specify `label` at a top level for these columns, as specifying it within `typeAttributes` will label the button, not the column header.